# Why is the calculation of fibonacci faster in javascript than haskell?

Tags: javascript, c, performance, haskell, fibonacci

As you can see in the examples below, javascript/node is much faster then haskell.
But haskell is compiled and based on C. In the example, you see that C is the fastest. How comes that haskell is so slow in comparison?

### JS executed by node:

```
function fib(n) {
    if ( n==0 || n==1 )
        return 1;

    return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1);
}
console.log(fib(30));
```

> $ time node fib.js
>   1346269
>   real  0m0,045s
>   user  0m0,040s
>   sys   0m0,004s

### haskell:

```
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = print (fib 30)
```

> $ ghc -o fibh fib.hs
>   $ time ./fibh
>   1346269
>   real  0m0,178s
>   user  0m0,168s
>   sys   0m0,000s

### c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) 
        return 1;

    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}

int main() {
    int f = fib(30);
    printf("cfib: %i\n", f);
}
```

> $ gcc fib.c -o fibc
>   $ time ./fibc
>   cfib: 1346269
>   real  0m0,023s
>   user  0m0,020s
>   sys   0m0,000s

## EDIT1:

### haskell with -O2 like suggested

```
$ ghc -O2 -o fibh fib.hs
$ time ./fibh
1346269
real 0m0,166s
user 0m0,160s
sys 0m0,004s
```

Comment: What if you add `-O2` to the compiler?

Comment: Haskell is probably defaulting to arbitrary-precision arithmetic too...

Comment: Is there a real reason for this? This is pretty much the definitive example of a poorly written algorithm for calculating Fibonacci values [O(2^n) calculations required].

Comment: Your tests are far too short to be meaningful, and because the code is so limited you're really only testing a fraction of each language. Furthermore, that's a terrible way of computing Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: And if you calculate them by hand, it will be even slower! Your question is too broad, different implementations of an algorithm have different runtime. If you want to dig deeper, see the machine code or how the bytecode is interpreted.

Comment: I did run the tests several times just to be sure it was not a one time thing, the times very just a little bit. And I understand that it is a poor way to compare them. I would just like why haskell is so much slower at computing the fibonacci in this particular way.

Comment: Calculating `fib(30)` using your recursive algorithm requires about 2.7 million calls to `fib()` and uses up lots of stack space. What you're testing is, in effect, the ability of these languages to save and retrieve their operating state under insane conditions. This isn't a realistic way of comparing their performance when operating normally.

Comment: thanks @squeamishossifrage that helps. I understand that the way of comparing their performance is not usefull. All I wanted to know is where the difference might come from. And now that you say stack I have a bit of an idea why this particular way of calculating fib is so different in the languages.

Comment: In addition to everything else that's been said: Did you force recompilation when adding `-O2` with `-fforce-recomp`? Otherwise, it's possible the recompilation did nothing. Furthermore, it should be possible to make it faster by adding a type signature `fib :: Int -> Int`, because otherwise the type will be defaulted to `Integer` which is significantly slower.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is just because of the difference between GMP `Integer`s and machine `Int`s:

```
% cat fib.hs
fib :: Int -> Int -- N.B. default is `Integer`
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = print (fib 30)


% ghc -O2 fib.hs && time ./fib
1346269
./fib  0.01s user 0.00s system 87% cpu 0.013 total
```

Comment: Not only that, but also whether the algorithm is tail recursive or not. [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence) shows the different algorithms.